# Questions on Spring MVC Component Scan

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using component scan to scan all the Controller,Service and DAO classes. If I put my Services and DAO interfaces on the same package with the implementer, would this cause the component scan process slower (Would it be like two times slower) ? Does it scan the subpackages as well ?

Comment: The scan happens ONCE, when Spring initializes at application startup. Unless you have a firm and very specific requirement regarding start-up time (which is very rare indeed), then do not bother with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will be slower. However you should not consider this as a factor when designing your package layout. Let the architecture drive placement of classes, not some arbitrary framework requirements and peculiarities.

Also you can filter out some classes/patterns if your application is *really* huge and you want to cut down the bootstrap time (see [*4.10.3 Using filters to customize scanning*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters)):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
  <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Stub.*Repository"/>
  <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                          expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

And yes, it does scan subpackages.